# i want to send input as multiple array formats using php

Tags: php

Hi my question is i want giving like request is the below arrays

```
["notes":{"email_id":"123","title":"John","notes":"15"},{"email_id":"15","title":"raj","notes":"hello"}],
```

but i got  array format as different

```
{"email_id":"10","notes": ["hi,hello,how"],"title":"hello"}
```

like this request only accepted please help me out...!!

```
<?php 

include('db.php');
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($input);
$json=array();
$email= $input->email_id;
$title = $input->title;
$notes= $input->notes;
$noteid= $input->note_id;
//echo json_encode($email);
if($email != '')
{
    foreach($email as $key=>$value){    
        if($noteid == '')
           $qry= mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `notes`( `email_id`, `title`, `notes`) VALUES ('$value','$title[$key]','$notes[$key]')");
        else
           $qry= mysqli_query($conn,"update `notes` set `email_id` = '$value', `title` = '$title[$key]', `notes` = '$notes[$key]' where id = '$noteid' ");
    }

    if($qry){
        $json = array("response" => "success", "status"=>1 ,"msg" => (($noteid == '') ? "insert ": "Update ")."done!");
    }
    else{
        $json = array("response" => "failed", "status"=>0 ,"msg" => (($noteid == '') ? "insert ": "Update ")."failed!");
    }
}
else
   $json = array("response" => "failed", "status"=>2 ,"msg" => "Request Not Reached!");

echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

above is my code in the above code sneding request format as multiple arrays but i am not getting i got  different sending request in one object 
how to solve this please find it using as raw data sending as postman request
thanking you in advance..!!

Comment: can you mention how you are preparing your json object

Comment: [{"email_id":"123","title":"John","notes":"15"},{"email_id":"15","title":"raj","notes":"hello"}]   my preparation is like this

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that you are receiving a string when you're expecting a json object then just do this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: hi echo json_encode($json); there in bottom line                                                            [{"email_id":"123","title":"John","notes":"15"},{"email_id":"15","title":"raj","notes":"hello"}] like this request i want

Comment: I really have no idea what you're saying.

Comment: but i am posting like this request {"email_id":"10","notes":["hi,hello,how"],"title":"hello"}  this array format request is working multiple arrays sending request

Answer (score 0):

Your json format is no correct

```
["notes":{"email_id":"123","title":"John","notes":"15"},{"email_id":"15","title":"raj","notes":"hello"}]
```

Correct format is

```
{"notes":[{"email_id":"123","title":"John","notes":"15"},{"email_id":"15","title":"raj","notes":"hello"}]}
```

than you can json decode in php using json_decode() function

`